# "Type" used as keyword raising an exception in RSpec but not in production or development environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, exception, rspec, keyword, rspec-rails

I'm working on a large web app that uses "type" as a column in the database for many of the tables. I understand that the word "type" is a keyword in Ruby, and should not be used as columns. However, why is it that I can still run the web app on my local server just fine, and that there aren't any apparent problems in the production environment? Will using "type" as a column potentially cause any trouble in the future?

This behavior is even more confusing because it does cause my RSpec feature tests to fail when creating a video (one of the resources) and then redirecting to the show view. (Note that the video as attributes that have associations with several of the tables which have "type" as a column).

This is the error message that is raised :

`"The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass:
&#39;reference&#39;. This error is raised because the column
&#39;type&#39; is reserved for storing the class in case of
inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn&#39;t intend it to
be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite
Tag.inheritance_column to use another column for that information."`

(Pulled from the HTML generated and displayed by `print page.body`)

Why would this exception to raised in  my test specs but not in the development or production environments? (I'm in charge of putting together test specs, so you have in your device on ways to get around this error, that would be helpful too!)

Notes on my configuration:

- I'm using Ruby 2.1.2 and rails 4.1.1
- Using capybara, factory girl, and capybara-WebKit as the web driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, there was an explicit type column in the schema but it was pulled from the subclass of the resource. The reason that RSpec had a problem is that I was trying to define the type column without making it a subclass. The solution was to use subclassed notation when inputting data into the type. In my case, this means the string in the type column needed to be put in as: `"Tags::Reference"` rather than `"reference"`.